# Change default options on attachment page

Tags: theme-development, post-meta, attachments

I'm currently adjusting someone's plugin, and they're pulling data from the attachment page. Rather than edit the whole plugin entirely, I'm after a quick fix.

Is it possible to change the wording on the attachment page? I'm ideally trying to change the word 'caption' to the word 'buy' — but I'm unsure how to override the wording shown?

Any help would be great.

Cheers.

Comment: Which plugin (& theme) are you referring to?

Comment: Advanced Custom Fields gallery plugin.

Comment: And what about the theme? And some code? We really can't help unless you give us some more info.